# android multi device development

Tags: android

I just begun with android development and i am wondering what is the most android sdk that reach most of devices that are using android platform.
after some researches i found sdk 2.3 (gingerbread) is the most used but still don't know if it support all gestures, animations, ... and also tablets and smartphones.

my first and last goal is to use the sdk that can most of smartphones and tablets with the max profit of android platform features.

any help is appreciated
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should just start with the lowest sdk version. *This ensures you start to develop for all devices.*

When you bump into a function that is not supported in that sdk version,
you could either **upgrade** your minimum sdk version, or **think about skipping the feature** if you think this will limit the device range too much.

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer is, android 2.1+, then you are handling 99.1% of all android phones currently.

Well the boring answer is that it depends.

Maybe you are in a market (corporate environment) were all your potential users got issued an android 1.6 phone.

Is it a tablet only app then go for 3.1+.

Anyway, for the statistics see the android developer dashboard for a breakdown:
http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

I suggest you use the android compatibility/support library to get fragments and other things on pre android 3.0 devices. Worth repeating, use fragments and your life will be easier, especially if you want it to look nice and work well on tablets too. Excellent libraries such as [actionbarsherlock.com](http://actionbarsherlock.com) are also of great help (actionbars on older versions).

Comment: if i developed my app using gingerbread 2.3.3 it cannot be supported by tablets ?
sdk 2.3.3 covers 65% of smartphones, if i'll go with 3.1+ i'll lose about 75 % of the market. any suggestion if i want to develop my app for both ? are tablets apps different than smartphones apps?

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need to know is available on the Android Developer Website.

1. Here is the [Android Distribution Chart](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html).
2. Information on supporting multiple platforms can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html).
3. Google provide a [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) which will, and continues to improve, support newer features in previous platforms.

Gingerbread is what most of the Android community is currently running, so use this as your minimum build sdk, or Froyo if you want to cover that laggin 20%. Set your target SDK to Jellybean and utilise the support library to maintain backwards compatibility.

There is plenty of information on the Android web site, especially in the [training section](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html). Enjoy and learn :-)